# mobile landing page - landscape issues

Tags: html, css, mobile

im creating a landing page, basically i used the picture as a background image and created the inputs with position absolute so the are floating above the image.

because all the CSS attributes are precentage, when i rotate my phone from portrait to landscape everything is glitching..

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="landing.js";></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="landing.css">
</head>
<body>

<form id='myform' name="form1"  action=''>

 <input type="email"  id="email" name="email"  onfocus="FocusClear('E-Mail', this)" onblur="BlurNoClear('E-Mail', this)" value="E-Mail">


<input type="text"  id="name" name="name"  onfocus="FocusClear('Name', this)" onblur="BlurNoClear('Name', this)" value="Name">    

    <button id="join_beta" onclick="sendForm();"> </button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
background-image:url('landing_new.jpg') !important;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 75% auto;
    background-position:  center top;
background-color:#38a3db;
}

#email{
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: 24.8%;
  margin-left: 60.5%;
  width: 19.5%;
  height: 6.5%;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
}

#name{
  border: 0px;
margin-top: 24.8%;
  margin-left: 39.6%;
  width: 19.5%;
  height: 6.5%;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}

#join_beta{
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: 29.2%;
  margin-left: 39.7%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 8%;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
body
{
background-image:url('landing_new.jpg') !important;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position:  center top;
background-color:#38a3db;
}

#email{
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: 32%;
  margin-left: 62%;
  width: 26%;
  height: 2.5%;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
    font-size: 8pt;
    text-align: center;
}

#name{
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: 32%;
  margin-left: 34.5%;
  width: 26%;
  height: 2.5%;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
  font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 0px;
}

#join_beta{
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: 37.5%;
  margin-left: 34.5%;
  width: 54%;
  height: 2.5%;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px;
} 
}


@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
body
{
background-image:url('landing_new.jpg') !important;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position:  center top;
background-color:#38a3db;
}

#email{
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: 32%;
  margin-left: 62%;
  width: 26%;
  height: 2.5%;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
    font-size: 6pt;
    text-align: center;
}


#name{
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: 32%;
  margin-left: 34.5%;
  width: 26%;
  height: 2.5%;
  background-color: transparent;


position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
  font-size: 6pt;
    padding: 0px;
}

#join_beta{
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: 37.5%;
  margin-left: 34.5%;
  width: 54%;
  height: 2.5%;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px;
} 
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: please be aware that if you want to use any of Bootstrap's native JS (which there is a lot of cool things to use!) You have to include bootstrap.js and jquery, otherwise they won't work.

You can find more info. about bootstrap here: http://getbootstrap.com

What you're looking for is responsive support and you're trying to do it manually. We all admire the grit it takes to do cool stuff all by yourself, but for something simple like this it's usually best to go with a responsive framework. I myself like bootstrap, and I coded this in about 5 minutes. With that being said this is pretty bare minimum but if you work with your CSS and add your BG images as well as positioning, it will do what you want it to do pretty well without glitches.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-12">
                     <form id='myform' name="form1"  action=''>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="email"  id="email" name="email"  onfocus="FocusClear('E-Mail', this)" onblur="BlurNoClear('E-Mail', this)" value="E-Mail"> 
                              <input type="text"  id="name" name="name"  onfocus="FocusClear('Name', this)" onblur="BlurNoClear('Name', this)" value="Name">
                              <button id="join_beta" onclick="sendForm();" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                         </div>
                    </form>
               </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>

</html>
```